# Creating a new text file in a newly created folder

Tags: c++

I'd like to be able to create a new folder and right afterwards create a new text file inside of it. The folder creation works fine but text file creation always fails.

```
        string ph = USER_INPUT;
        USER_INPUT.clear();
        cout <<  "\n Write the name/ID of a lesson. Write 'cancel' to cancel.\n\n Lesson: ";
        while (USER_INPUT == "" and USER_INPUT != "cancel")
        {
            getline(cin,USER_INPUT);
        }
        string ph2 = USER_INPUT;
        string pathholder = "school\\" + ph;
        const char *pathcreator = pathholder.c_str();
        mkdir(pathcreator);
        pathholder = "school\\" + ph + "\\" + ph2 + ".txt";
        fstream file;
        file.open(pathcreator);
```

When I print out pathcreator once it holds the desired .txt path, it writes it just fine so I must have an error in my code but I can't figure out where.

Please help.

Comment: Note that you're calling `file.open(pathcreator)` and not `file.open(pathholder)`.

Answer (score 0):

mkdir is deprecated, prefer _mkdir. Avoid using namespace std unless in pointless code examples.
I cleaned up your code a little bit while trying to keep the shape of it.
If you couldn't created your file, it might have been due to the default flags of `fstream`. Do you want to input or output to file or both ? this code will do output to file.
see this for more information on flags :
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/
you could also open with fstream as such :
`file.open(fileplace,fstream::out);`

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <direct.h>
using namespace std;
void foo() {
string pathToFolder = "C:\\";
string innerFolder;
string fileName = "aFile";
cout << "\n Write the name/ID of a lesson. Write 'cancel' to cancel.\n\n Lesson: ";
while (innerFolder == "" and innerFolder != "cancel")
{
    getline(cin, innerFolder);
}
pathToFolder += innerFolder; //use += to append string or const char * to string
int error = _mkdir(pathToFolder.c_str());
if (error == 0)
    cout << "folder created" << endl;
else
    cout << "error creating folder" << endl;
string fileplace = pathToFolder;
fileplace += "\\";
fileplace += fileName += ".txt";
ofstream file;
file.open(fileplace);
if (file.is_open())
    cout << "file created" << endl;
else
    cout << "couldn't create file" << endl;
}
void main() {
    foo();
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

`const char *pathcreator = pathholder.c_str();`

You obtain a `char*` pointer to the internal data for `pathholder`, assign it to `pathcreator`, and then pass `pathcreator` to `mkdir()`.  OK so far.

But then, on this line:

`pathholder = "school\\" + ph + "\\" + ph2 + ".txt";`

You change the internal data of `pathholder`, *invalidating* `pathcreator`, but you are using `pathcreator` afterwards on this line, which is *undefined behavior*:

`file.open(pathcreator);`

I suggest you get rid of `pathcreator` altogether, and just use `pathholder.c_str()` directly in the calls to `mkdir()` and `open()`:

```cpp
string pathholder = "school\\" + ph;
mkdir(pathholder.c_str());
pathholder += ("\\" + ph2 + ".txt");
fstream file;
file.open(pathholder.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both user and Remy. I ended up using both of your suggestions and the final code ended like this:

```
        string ph = USER_INPUT;
        USER_INPUT.clear();
        cout <<  "\n Write the name/ID of a lesson. Write 'cancel' to cancel.\n\n Lesson: ";
        while (USER_INPUT == "" and USER_INPUT != "cancel")
        {
            getline(cin,USER_INPUT);
        }
        string ph2 = USER_INPUT += ".txt";
        string pathholder = "school\\" + ph;
        _mkdir(pathholder.c_str());
        pathholder += "\\" + ph2;
        ofstream file;
        file.open(pathholder.c_str());
        file.close();
        if (USER_INPUT != "cancel")
        cout << "\n Subject added to database.\n\n\n   ";
```

I didn't know xyz.c_str() could be used to define a creation variable x). Knowing this, pathcreator really was of no importance. As per what I wanted to do with the file - just create it. Afterwards the function gets finished and once it is accessed again those files would be work-with-able.

Thank you both for solving my problem.